# How to display single data using map method for json datatype in React js

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

const ProfileView = () => {

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/customer/showData', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setData(response.data);
                setisLoaded(true);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);


    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    const [isloaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);
    let customer = null
    let view1 = null;
    let view2 = null;
    let view3 = null;
    let view4 = null;

    if (isloaded) {
        data.map(data1 => {
            customer = data1
            console.log(customer);
        })
    }
```

**I am getting type error data.map is not a function I am trying to getting 1 user data using map method I am using get method to get resources**

Comment: what does your console.log(response) yields ?

Answer (score 0):

This could really use some more context. First of all, `data` is not initialised. To do so, pass an argument to the `useState()` function, an empty `[]`. See if that's enough, because you can not call `.map()` on an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that whatever data is, calling `.map` on it doesn't works. In other words, it means that the `.map` method is unavailable on it. If you console.log it you would have undefined and this is because at the first render and until you setData to an array.

To handle this issue React provides us with a way to initialise data with a default value. In your case it might be handy to avoid having this error

```
// we initialise data with an empty array so that it will not be equal to 
// undefined during the first render
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
```

> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

from : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Another solution would have to isolate your code under an if condition, if the data is there, meaning if it's not undefined, then do this, but it will force you to scatter your dom returning statements. (doesn't mean it's wrong though)

PS: also, make sure to call setData, it seems you have given us an incomplete code since I don't see setData called.

Comment: Even after passing argument I am still getting error I amusing fetch to get data from data database

Comment: then please complete your post with more code. show us how to you fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem might be that the response that you are getting back from the server is not an array and thus does not have the .map method. check that when you call

```
setData(response.data);
```

that response.data is actually an array and not a string or object.  axios will only parse the json if the response has content-type:application/json header set.